# Custom Control to use Cursor Hand

Tags: c#

I've made a custom control in C# and anytime that the user's cursor is hovering over the custom control I want the cursor to be displayed as the 'Hand'. Where do i place the code to do such a thing?

```
????.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

in order to make it so the Hand Cursor is being displayed when hovering over this custom control?

```
namespace CustomRangeBar
{
    public partial class RangeBar : UserControl
    {
        public RangeBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            this.ForeColor = SystemColors.Highlight; // set the default color the rangeBar
            this.Click += new EventHandler(RangeBar_Click); 
        }

        protected float percent = 0.0f; // Protected because we don't want this to be accessed from the outside
        // Create a Value property for the rangeBar
        public float Value
        {
            get
            {
                return percent;
            }
            set
            {
                // Maintain the value between 0 and 100
                if (value < 0) value = 0;
                else if (value > 100) value = 100;
                percent = value;
                label1.Text = value.ToString();
                //redraw the rangeBar every time the value changes
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor); //create brush that will draw the background of the range bar
            // create a linear gradient that will be drawn over the background. FromArgb means you can use the Alpha value which is the transparency
            LinearGradientBrush lb = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), Color.FromArgb(255, Color.White), Color.FromArgb(50, Color.White), LinearGradientMode.Vertical);

            // calculate how much has the rangeBar to be filled for 'x' %
            int width = (int)((percent / 100) * this.Width);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lb, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            b.Dispose(); lb.Dispose();
        }

        private void RangeBar_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // maintain the label in the center of the rangeBar
            label1.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - 21 / 2 - 4, this.Height / 2 - 15 / 2);
        }

    }
}

public void RangeBar_Click(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    // This get executed if the pictureBox gets clicked
    label1.text = "Increment 1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) derives from Control and therefore should already have a Cursor property inherited from that class. Do you not see a Cursor property in code/Properties?

Comment: where is that located?

Comment: ahhh i see it now. My apologies. Thank you

Comment: i searched around online for a bit and couldn't find this.